Deep Link only opens app but not the linked route in Expo?
I'm using expo file based routing and deep links.
A few days ago I got it working, but something broke it and since that I can't figure out what.
my files structure looks something like this:
├── MobileApp
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── (auth)
|   │   │   ├── (tabs)
|   |   │   │   ├── profile
|   |   │   │   └── search
│   │   │   ├── screens
│   │   │   │   ├── rooms
│   │   │   │   │   └── [id].tsx
│   │   │   │   ├── sessions
│   │   │   │   │   └── [id].tsx
│   │   │   │   ├── hosts
│   │   │   │   │   └── [id].tsx
│   │   │   └── _layout.tsx

my deeplink like this: myapp://screens/rooms/03131-31231-12313
According to the docs this deep link should work, and navigation to this exact route works when testing it in the app with a button. But not when coming from outside of the app.
Using this deep link will just open the app if the app is already open. But not navigate to it. I get the warning: Navigation state parsed from the URL containes route not present in the root navigator. However, if the app is been closed, I see the correct screen for a sec and then it redirects to the starting screen again.
Using uri-scheme didn't work as I get an adb that it couldn't be found.
I tried using all different kind of combinations with the deep link. Using three slashes, using (auth)/screens, using a non dynamic route.
I also rebuilt the app several times.
